# can getJSON be used to get a value from an html tag id already rendered by a page?? json_decode?

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

what i mean by this is after an html page is rendered, how can i get the value by using the html tag id??

ex: get the value of date by using td_date in my JS function??
below the code that puts the data on the page: listSuccess.php

```
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $msg)
{ 
    echo "<tr id='td_id' value='$msgId'</tr>";
    $date = add_date($msg->getCreatedAt(),$hr=2);
echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_date'>".$date."</td>";
    <td align='left' id='td_subject'>
     <a href="<?php echo url_for('messagebox/read?cursor=').$cursor ?>" style='color:#ff0000 !important' class='spn_small_red_rbc'><?php echo $msg->getSubject();?></a>
   </td>
   echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_from'>".$unique_code_from."</td>";
   echo "<td id='block_url'>( ".$block_url." )</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   ++$cursor;
```

}

so in my JS:

```
function ax_get_new_msg_details()
{
var mTimer; 
$.getJSON('/apps_dev.php/messagebox/newMessageDetails', function(data) 
{
    var messageExists = $('#' + data.td_id).length > 0;
    if (!messageExists)
    {
        mTimer = setTimeout('ax_get_new_msg_details()',30000);
        var str='<tr id="' + data.td_id + '">';
        str += "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_date'>"+data.td_date+'</td>';
        str += "<td align='left' id='td_subject'><a href='#' style='color:#ff0000 !important' class='spn_small_red_rbc'>"+data.td_subject+"</a></td>";
        str += "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_from'>"+data.td_from +"</td>";
        //str += "<td id='block_url'>"+data.block_url+"</td>";
        str +='<tr>';
        var tbl = $('#td_date').parents('table');
        $(tbl).append(str);
        }
    });
}
```

then newMessageDetails.php in my actions.class.php

```
public function executeNewMessageDetails(sfWebRequest $request)
{  
    $profile_id = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('profile_id','zero');  
    $new_msgs = RcMessageBoxTablePeer::getNewMessages($profile_id);
    if (count($new_msgs) >= 1)
    {
        foreach ($new_msgs as $row)
        {
           $date = $row->getCreatedAt();
           $subject = $row->getSubject();
           $from = $row->getProfileIdFrom();
           $id = $row->getId();
           $uc_record = RcProfileTablePeer::getById($from);
           $uc_from = $uc_record->getUniqueCode();
           //$block_url = 'Block User',"blocklist/block?unqiue_code=$uc_from",'class=link_medium_blue');
        }
        $output = array("td_date" => $date, "td_subject" => $subject, "td_from" => $uc_from, "td_id" => $id);
    }
    else
       $output = "";

    return $this->renderText(json_encode($output));
}
```

the data that i get from the JS function is correct but i need to somehow know that what is actually already on my page ie what was rendered already differs from what json returns and if data differs...update the page with the new json data

any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not include your td_id in your tr tag and just compare the incoming id with the existing id?

```
var str='<tr id="' + data.td_id + '">';
```

Then in your update put this if condition around your code:

```
var messageExists = $('#' + data.td_id).length > 0;
if (!messageExists) {
// your existing code
}
```

Comment: Looak better. I edited it further so that the initial tr generated by your pager code also has the td_id

Comment: Helloise, apparently my edit doesn't get to appear until it is peer-reviewed so in summary, I updated the first tr in your first block of code to have id='{$msg->getId()}'. I don't know how your $msg object is structured, but basically you need to make sure the id attribute of your TR has the message id so that when the javascript checks it in the messageExists logic it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use firefox and the web developer tool bar it not only allows you to see the source code but also allows you to view the generated source code, plus lots of other very useful tools hope this helps you.

Comment: have firebug for chrome on can see everything that happens :) i just somehow by the time my json runs..know what was already rendered so i can check it against what json returned :)